# Null comparison Segmentation fault

Tags: c

hello Im trying to implement a linked list

here is a small funtion that navigates to the bottom of the list

```
struct list* nav(struct list* head){
     struct list* search;
     search = head;
     while(search->next != NULL){
       search = search->next;
     }
     return search;
}
```

im getting a segfault when i do compare search->next with null any advice on how i can avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a NULL `head`...

Comment: `while( search && search->next )` would probably do what you want, so long as your caller is crystal clear that a null initial head will produce a null result. And fyi, you can throw out `search` entirely and just use `head` directly, as it is C and thus pass by value. e.g. `while (head && head->next) head = head->next; return head;`

Answer (score 4):

You should check if `search` is not `NULL` before performing dereference.

```
struct list* nav(struct list* head){
     struct list* search;
     search = head;
     if (search == NULL) return search; /* perform NULL check */
     while(search->next != NULL){
       search = search->next;
     }
     return search;
}
```

Also you have to make sure that `next` in your list contains only valid pointers or `NULL`. It mustn't contain invalid data such as an indeterminate value of a buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Add an edge case.

```
struct list* nav(struct list* head){
     struct list* search;
     search = head;
     if (search == NULL) {
         return NULL;
     }

     while(search->next != NULL){
       search = search->next;
     }
     return search;
}
```